# Can not Push on Github through Ubuntu Terminal

Tags: git, github, ssh-keys, git-push

I am trying to push to github from my Ubuntu machine.
I am able to Push from Visual Studio Code terminal, but can not Push from Ubuntu Terminal or Android Studio Terminal.
Every time I try to Push from Terminal or android studio terminal, it asks for username and password.
Even though I enter my valid username and password it says

> remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
> remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.
> fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/mdshadatrahman/advanced_flutter.git/'

I have added ssh key using `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "myemailaddress"`

But I can push form VS Code Terminal without any problem.

 How can I solve this problem? 
Thanks

Almost forgot to add - I am able to Push using Android Studio shortcut(CRTL + SHIFT + K).

Comment: it's because you are using https protocol instead of ssh, which has already stopped support for using actual password

Comment: thank you @PhuNgo. it was the actual casue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the remote uses the HTTPS protocol (password based) instead of SSH (key based).

```
$ git remote -l
```

should list your remotes, e. g.

```
origin  https://github.com:darmiel/eeee (fetch)
origin  https://github.com:darmiel/eeee (push)
```

If your origin remote starts with `https://` you're on the wrong protocol.
Change the HTTPS remote to SSH using `git remote set-url`:

```
$ git remote set-url origin git@github.com:darmiel/eeee.git
```

you can see the SSH url by clicking on the "Clone" button on GitHub:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. My problem is solved. I just had to use ssh instead of https. Thanks again.

Comment: `$ git remote -l`, `error: unknown switch 'l'`